# Did the merchant just want to make a sale, or transmit greyscale?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In season 5 of Game of Thrones, we hear the tale of how

> Stannis’ daughter Shireen was infected with greyscale by a doll sold to him by a merchant from Dorne.

The way the story is told, it sounds like Stannis suspected that the merchant knew he was likely to buy the item, but it’s not clear to me whether he thought the merchant just wanted to make a sale, or whether he thought the merchant actually knew the doll carried greyscale.

Is there anything in the books, or anything I missed in the show, indicating that this was an intentional infection plot?

Because, as we know, everywhere in the world, they hurt little girls.

Comment: We also know that greyscale can be cured with fire.

Comment: @Omegacron `axe and sword and cleaver` are mentioned by Tyrion as possible remedies. :)

Comment: @TLP: I'm not entirely sure, but isn't there a tale somewhere in the books, where even cutting off the infected body parts did not "cure" grayscale and the disease actually reappered a little later. I'm not entirely certain though ...

Comment: @user1129682 Yes, it is mentioned that it is not a sure thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did not get the impression that Stannis thought the greyscale was intentional. Rather, he thought the merchant was being the usual level of shady, in trying to "trick" the rich lord into buying things he otherwise wouldn't.

I'm not sure what motivation a travelling merchant would have had to poison the daughter of a lord, especially the brother of the King. Even if he wanted to, carrying around something infected with greyscale would be risky. In fact, from the story, I didn't quite understand how she caught greyscale from a doll if no one else that handled the doll caught it. Given how easily

> Jorah

caught it after a fleeting contact, it would seem that carrying around an infected toy would be suicidal.

As far as the novels go, I believe this merchant story was invented entirely for the show; I don't remember any explanation for how Shireen caught greyscale other than she did. In fact, there are hints in *A Dance with Dragons* that greyscale may not be entirely a natural phenomenon.

Comment: “I'm not sure what motivation a travelling merchant would have had to poison the daughter of a lord” — oh yeah, none personally. But (in theory) the merchant might not have been a real merchant, or have been in the employ of someone in Dorne who wanted revenge on someone involved in Robert’s Rebellion, which I understand went badly for some people from Dorne.

Comment: “I didn't quite understand how she caught greyscale from a doll if no one else that handled the doll caught it” — Yeah, that’s one thing that made me wonder whether it was intentional, or even if the greyscale was intended for Stannis.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite true, but nothing in Stannis' story gave any hint that the guy was more than a merchant, which I would have expected to be a key element otherwise. But still, it's just my impression.

Comment: This is a bit speculative, but some real-life conditions come from microbes whose spores that can lie dormant in unsuitable conditions (too dry, hot or cold) and slowly activate and propagate when conditions become suitable. So, it's plausible that the grayscale microbes couldn't thrive on cool dry wood, and died leaving spores; then, extended content with skin (warmth and moisture) enabled them to reactivate. I think he said she held it to her face every night for days or weeks?

Comment: @user568458 that's possible, but it's slightly at odds with how incredibly contagious greyscale seems to be in other cases... IMO this was just a misstep by the TV writers.

Comment: So what I'm saying is, a grayscale carrier's skin would be teeming with live microbes, which can transfer and start propogating instantly, while the doll would only have inactive spores, which need a long time in conditions of modest warmth and moisture to become active and propagate live microbes. It's speculative, and it's certainly possible the writers just messed up, but I believe there are real-life conditions like this

Comment: @user568458: aha, yeah could be something like that.

Comment: I don't think that the Jorah case is comparable. We don't have the specifics of Jorah's contact with the disease. Maybe one of the Stone Men touched him directly, or worse. Maybe something else. All we know is that he is like the guy in a zombie movie that got bitten, and will later turn into a zombie when everyone is locked safely inside a room for some time.

Answer (score 5):

Re-reading Stannis' quote explaining how Shireen caught grayscale he seems to believe the merchant just wanted to make a sale.

> Stannis Baratheon: When you were an infant, the Dornish trailer landed on Dragonstone. **His goods were junk except for one wooden doll. He'd even sewn a dress on it in the colors of our House. No doubt he'd heard of your birth, and assumed new fathers were easy targets.** I still remember how you smiled when **I put that doll in your cradle, and you pressed it to your cheek.** By the time we burnt the doll, it was too late. I was told you would die. Or worse, the grayscale would go slow. Let you grow just enough to know the world before taking it away from you. Everyone advised me to send you to the ruins of Valyria to live out your short life with the Stone men, before the sickness spread to the castle. I told them all to go to hell. **I called in every maester on this side of the world. Every healer, every apothecary.** They stopped the disease and saved your life. Because you did not belong across the world with the bloody Stone men. You are the Princess Shireen of House Baratheon. And you are my daughter.
>   <sub>Game of Thrones, Season 5 Episode 4, "Sons of the Harpy"</sub>

As you can see the merchant and Stannis also handle the doll at some point so it seems unlikely that he would have done it on purpose considering the risk of contracting it himself.

As for why only Shireen caught the disease and the other characters didn't well we don't really know how the disease works. From the show we know of 3 other characters that come into contact with it and only one of them get's the disease, again details unknown. Jorah seems to catch it with his fight with the Stone men, however, it is never shown how he catches it, though likely he was grabbed on the skin. Tyrion on the other hand gets dragged underwater by them so again he likely only got touched on the clothes, the scene can be viewed here:

The other person we see in contact with it is Sam when he saves Jorah in Season 7. He is is full protective clothing and so probably never touches the stuff.

[image: Sam operates on Jorah]

As such it would appear that you need an extended exposure to the disease to catch it. I think @user568458 puts it quite well in a couple of comments above, though it is only speculation.

> This is a bit speculative, but some real-life conditions come from microbes whose spores that can lie dormant in unsuitable conditions (too dry, hot or cold) and slowly activate and propagate when conditions become suitable. So, it's plausible that the grayscale microbes couldn't thrive on cool dry wood, and died leaving spores; then, extended content with skin (warmth and moisture) enabled them to reactivate. I think he said she held it to her face every night for days or weeks?
>   <sub>[user568458 Jun 25 '15 at 17:11](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93738/did-the-merchant-just-want-to-make-a-sale-or-transmit-greyscale#comment212076_93746)</sub>
>
> So what I'm saying is, a grayscale carrier's skin would be teeming with live microbes, which can transfer and start propogating instantly, while the doll would only have inactive spores, which need a long time in conditions of modest warmth and moisture to become active and propagate live microbes. It's speculative, and it's certainly possible the writers just messed up, but I believe there are real-life conditions like this
>   <sub>[user568458 Jun 25 '15 at 17:15](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93738/did-the-merchant-just-want-to-make-a-sale-or-transmit-greyscale#comment212080_93746)</sub>